# Jupyter Notebook not opening because of weird error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When I try to open jupyter notebook the result is:

> Fata error in launcher: Failed to open executable

I tried to google it yet nothing has matched my error. I don't know what to do any more. I've tried reinstalling Python so many times and I still get this result. My Python is version 3.8.1 by the way.

Comment: Is that the entire error message?

Comment: Have you got any stacktrace at all? Or perhaps some code? Currently people have to use their magical glass orb's to figure out what you are doing and mine is recharging.

Comment: Did you mean "Fatal error"?

Answer (score 0):

Try to launch it with `python -m jupyter notebook`

If this works, check if you the scripts folder is in your PATH: for example I am running python 3.6 so i added `C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts` to my PATH.